# Percent sign in URL doesn't match rewrite rule (ASP.NET MVC project on IIS)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

I have an URL in the form

```
/search/search-terms
```

which is described in the RewriteRules.config to match the regular expression

```
^search/(.*)$
```

The action rewrites it to

```
Search.aspx?value={R:1}
```

with `appendQueryString` set to `true`.

Everything is fine until I put an ampersand (&) in the search terms. I encode "term1&term2" to the URL string

```
/search/term1%26term2
```

but this URL is only matched up to `term1`. I'm not sure what causes this, whether the presence of the percent sign in the URL or a wrong encoding. What I know is that `Request["value"]` returns `term1` only, so this is not a problem with my logic but with the URL rewrite itself.

How can I get the whole string, including the escaped ampersand? My logic then correctly decodes the escaped entity; I know this because it works in localhost, where no rewriting is performed.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is no solution: the percent sign breaks the rewrite rules matching. I had to encode and decode the query string, replacing special characters that get URL-enconded to percent-sign-tokens (like space to %20 and ampersand to %26) with other words.